# Do static electronic indicators, that does not need power, exist? (equivalent of epaper, eink)

Tags: led, low-power, indicator

Hello I am looking for some way to indicate an signal in long term, but with no power consumption (power needed just for state switching). Are there any lowcost indicators based on epaper or eink or just paper pixel flipping sides with different colors?

I would be glad for every hint.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flip-disc_display

Comment: I'm sure there were also miniature flip-disk displays. I seem to remember using such in an avionics project in the 60's.

Comment: https://flipdots.com/en/home/

Comment: "Flip-dot" is another term. There are some that look like a regular panel indicator. Snap! @Janka.

Comment: What are you looking to indicate? Some electromechanical solution might do

Comment: Reflective LCD’s are  low power displays but everything draws power to change the contents. Defining that requirement is your requirement.

Comment: What is the signal and what indication do you want?

Comment: In the late 19th and early 20th century there were mechanical indicators and annunciators in mansions. They told the hired help where the call came from.

Comment: Thay you all for your responses. Those flipdots are almost what i am looking for. But I need it for wearables, so I want to find some smaller ”on-chip” dimensions.

Comment: "*... but I need it for wearables.*" Please [edit] that requirement into your question.

Comment: i think  you can draw on a magnadoodle with a magnetic coil. maybe reversing the poles clears it?